# How to approach the functional equation $\frac{f(x+T)}{f(x)} = g(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, functional-equations

I am trying (for fun!) to study the ongoing COVID-19 pandemic and have the following question. we know that an exponential function satisfies the following functional equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x+T)}{f(x)} = e^T = \text{constant}
\end{equation}
for some period $T$. For instance the function $f(x)=2^x$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} = 2
\end{equation}
Now, since here in Italy the growth rate of the infected is falling, the function describing the total amount of covid-19 cases since the start of the outbreak might satisfy the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x+T)}{f(x)} = g(x)\qquad \text{with $g$ decreasing to 1}
\end{equation}

My question is this: how to solve this, is the solution existing, is it unique? Any hint on how I could approach this?

Comment: The solution is not unique. Already the exponential solution was not unique: If $f$ is a solution then so is $c\cdot f$ for any constant. Apart from that, $f$ can behave arbitrarily on an initial interval $[0,T)$, say

Comment: You need to read more on epidemiology models. This is a good try but to say bluntly, too naive.

Comment: @timur Ok I am not really interested in having a good model for the epidemic (I know about SIR models etc) but I thought that this mathematical problem was interesting

Comment: agree with timur's comment: spreading is a [multiplicative diffusion process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion) quite similar to nuclear fission

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be given for $x\in[0,T)$, and let $g(x)$ be given for $x\in[0,b]$, for some $T>0$ and $b\geq T$. Then the equation
$$
f(x+T)=g(x)f(x) ,
$$
has a unique solution for $x\in[0,b]$.
In other words, the solution $f$ is unique as a function defined on $[0,T+b]$.